# How long TVS diode lifespan?

Tags: protection, tvs, lightning

Do TVS diode have a lifespan? Do TVS diode protect against how many lightning strike during own lifespan? Can ı calculate life expectancy? I don't found any document about this issue

Comment: you're talking about this as if lightning has a certified voltage and current rating

Comment: [link](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/134888-white-paper-calculating-life-expectancy-of-surge-protector-pd-out-sp11#:~:text=A%20good%20quality%20GDT%20with,field%20and%20ultimately%20saves%20cost.&text=The%20life%20expectancy%20of%20PD,the%20USA%20is%207.27%20years.) I am looking same as this document. The document about GDT.

Comment: TSV have their own current and voltage rating. You can estimate whether they would hold it against the lightning, no? I mean, there are rough estimates on lightning available, if your diode can handle that surge current with a good safe margin, should be good. It would be nice if you attached a pair of datasheets of diodes you're considering

Comment: @Ilya and a datasheet for that lightning :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your questions

> Do TVS diode protect against how many lightning strike during own
> lifespan?

is addressed in details in [Microsemi's MicroNote 135](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/129581-micronote-135-failure-mechanisms-for-transient-voltage-suppressors). I am citing section **1 Failure Mechanisms for Transient Voltage Suppressors** for your convenience:

> The silicon p-n junction TVS device is also identified as an “ABD,” or
> avalanche breakdown diode transient voltage suppressor in IEC or JEDEC
> standards, such as JESD210. When avalanche breakdown occurs, the
> silicon p-n junction device conducts a large amount of current (IPP)
> to ground in front of the protected load for a short duration
> transient that is typically 1 ms or less. During this short event, the
> TVS device clamps the voltage to a safe level (VC). This also results
> in significant power (PPP) and heating at the p-n junction. **This can
> repeat itself for random recurring transient events indefinitely
> within the rating of the TVS, but only if there is sufficient time for
> the device to cool before the next event occurs.**  Rapid repetitive
> surges that would cause cumulative heating effects are not part of the
> normal rating of a TVS, as described in MicroNote 133. **Silicon p-n
> junction TVS devices are unlike metal oxide varistor (MOV) devices
> that can degrade over time after many random recurring surges within
> their maximum rating.**

Emphases are mine, the phrases emphasized directly answer your question:

> can repeat ... **indefinitely within the rating of the TVS** ... **if
> there is sufficient time for the device to cool** before the next event
> occurs.

and oppose TVS and MOV devices

> ... that **can degrade over time** after many random recurring surges
> **within their maximum rating**.

to the benefit of TVS devices as concerns device degradation under repetitive surges.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @V.V.T these informations were very useful for me.

Comment: And @Ilya thank you for your interest